# nonce_user_logged_out to assign guests unique nonces breaks ajax calls

Tags: ajax, security, nonce

I've been researching implementing unique guest nonces via nonce_user_logged_out - [for reference](https://github.com/WordPress/Documentation-Issue-Tracker/issues/876). So far I can generate nonces for the random UID I create:

```
add_filter( 'nonce_user_logged_out', 'uniqueUid', 10, 2 );

function uniqueUid($uid, $action){
    if($action == 'nonce_action_name'){
        return time();
    }
}
```

On page load, this uid is hooked serverside and generates a unique nonce, which is then localized via `wp_localize_script()` this functions correctly.

On Ajax calls, the correct unique nonce is passed back to the server via Ajax, but when that value is plugged into `wp_verify_nonce($nonce,'nonce_action_name')` it can't be verified because the UID defaults to 0 serverside.

I can manually `wp_set_current_user()` - the area that prevents this from functioning - but I can't use a random number - any number used has to be available in the wp_users table Primary key as a reference. So random uid values don't work.

I don't understand how people use this to generate guest nonces that can be verified using randomly generated UIDs. I've looked around without any luck.

The idea is that guests will all have unique nonces using this system since uid 0 nonces aren't ideal.If anyone has any insight, I would appreciate it.